# Angular - spy not recognising function being called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test one of my feature modules but I'm struggling. My last test fails because the spy doesn't think that the method is called. Not even if I move the `this.translate.use(this.currentLanguage.i18n)` call outside of the subscribe block.

This is the feature component:

```
export class LanguagesComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  public languages = [
    {
      id: '0',
      name: this.translate.stream('LANGUAGES.SWEDISH'),
      i18n: 'sv',
      flag: {
        src: './assets/img/sv.svg'
      }
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      name: this.translate.stream('LANGUAGES.ENGLISH'),
      i18n: 'en',
      flag: {
        src: './assets/img/en.svg'
      }
    }
  ];

  public currentLanguage: any;

  private storageSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private cs: ClientStorage,
    private notifications: NotificationsApi,
    private router: Router,
    private translate: TranslateService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    const storedLanguage: any = this.cs.getItem(AppConstants.currentLanguage);

    this.currentLanguage = FindObjectByQuery(this.languages, 'i18n', storedLanguage);

    // Listen for when the language changes from other places than this component
    this.storageSubscription = this.cs.logger$
      .filter(data => data && data.key === AppConstants.currentLanguage)
      .subscribe((currentLanguage: any) => {

        if (currentLanguage) {

          this.currentLanguage = FindObjectByQuery(this.languages, 'i18n', currentLanguage.value);

          // Set the current language to use
          this.translate.use(this.currentLanguage.i18n);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.storageSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  selectLanguage(language: any): void {

    this.cs.setItem(AppConstants.currentLanguage, language.i18n);

    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);

    this.notifications.newNotification({message: this.translate.instant('NOTIFICATIONS.LANGUAGES.CHANGED'), theme: 'success'});
  }
}
```

And these are my tests so far:

```
describe('[UNIT] LanguagesComponent', () => {

  let component: LanguagesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LanguagesComponent>;
  let translate: Location;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ModuleImports
      ],
      providers: [
        TranslateService
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [LanguagesComponent, DummyComponent]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LanguagesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    translate = TestBed.get(TranslateService);

    // Make sure ngOnInit runs
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the component', async(() => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should have a current language when the component has loaded', () => {
    expect(component.currentLanguage).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should have the needed properties in the current language', () => {

    const currentLanguage = component.currentLanguage;

    expect(currentLanguage.id).toBeTruthy();
    expect(currentLanguage.name).toBeTruthy();
    expect(currentLanguage.i18n).toBeTruthy();
    expect(currentLanguage.flag.src).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call the use method of TranslateService with the current language i18n property', () => {

    const spy = spyOn(translate, 'use').and.callThrough();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(component.currentLanguage.i18n);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your test you created a spy and then you immediately trying to verify the call. But there was no call.

There can be two possible solution for this.

1. Move your `spyOn` before `fixture.detect` changes in `beforeEach`.
2. After creating the spy, call/trigger appropriate method which will/should trigger the expected call. In this case `fixture.detectChanges` needs to be called.

Note: I didn't run your tests for any other issues but the basic issue is the missing call between spy creation and spy use.

Comment: Thank you! I moved my `fixture.detectChanges()` AFTER my spy declaration inside of my synchronous `beforeEach()` block and it is now working as expected.